# Create a login system using basic python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, if-statement

I am just a beginner and want to build a password login system using python
I want it to print 'Login successful' if I enter correct pin, on entering an incorrect pin it should give 3 attempts and then a countdown of 10 seconds and ask the pin for 1 last time after 10 seconds and then `break`.

this is my attempt:

```
from pyautogui import countdown
password = 5266
chances = 0
while chances < 3:
    pin = int(input("ENTER THE CORRECT PIN > "))
    while not password.isdigit():
        print("Enter Four Digit Number")
    if pin == password:
     print("login successful".upper())
     break
    elif pin != chances:
      print("enter correct pin".title())
    chances += 1
else:
    print("too many attempts try again after 10sec ".title())
    seconds = 10
    countdown(seconds)
    input("ENTER THE CORRECT PIN > ")
    print("login sucessfully".title())
    print("gud bye".upper())
```

Comment: What problems are you having and what have you done to fix the problem?

Comment: on entering incorrect pin once it exits with an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from time import sleep

password = 5266
chances = 0
while chances < 3:
    pin = input("ENTER THE CORRECT PIN > ")
    while not pin.isdigit() or len(pin) != 4:  # isdigit is only an operation for strings
        print("ENTER A FOUR DIGIT NUMBER")
        pin = input("ENTER THE CORRECT PIN > ")
    pin = int(pin)
    if pin == password:
        print("LOGIN SUCCESSFUL")
        break
    chances += 1
else:
    print("TOO MANY ATTEMPTS. TRY AGAIN IN 10 SECONDS")
    seconds = 10
    sleep(seconds)
    if input("ENTER THE CORRECT PIN > ") == password:
        print("LOGIN SUCCESSFUL")
    else:
        print("GOOD BYE")
```